# Webkit Speech - Javascript trigger mic listen

Tags: jquery, webkit, speech-recognition

```
<input x-webkit-speech />
```

Gives in webkit browsers:

[image: speech input]

Is there a way to to trigger the mic click with javascript ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not at this time.

You can visit http://www.webkit.org/ and leave a suggestion for them to add this in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Old question but this is now possible, ish.

http://updates.html5rocks.com/2013/01/Voice-Driven-Web-Apps-Introduction-to-the-Web-Speech-API